# UIActionSheet isn't loading actions for button indexes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiactionsheet

I have set up some code so that when two separate buttons are tapped on a UIActionSheet, there will be two different actions. Unfortunately nothing happens when the buttons are pressed. The UIActionSheet just unloads as if a cancel button had been pressed.

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)saveFile:(id)sender {

UIActionSheet *saveFileSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:@"iDHSB Download Centre" 
                       delegate:nil 
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"  
                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                       otherButtonTitles:@"Download File", @"Show My Files", nil] 
                      autorelease];

 [saveFileSheet showInView:webView];

}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

NSLog(@"Action Sheet Button Pressed");

if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Show My Files");

        [self.window presentModalViewController:savedFiles animated:YES];

}

if(buttonIndex == 2){

        NSLog(@"Saving File");

        // Get the URL of the loaded ressource
        NSURL *theResourcesURL = [[webView request] URL];
        // Get the filename of the loaded ressource form the UIWebView's request URL
        NSString *filename = [theResourcesURL lastPathComponent];
        NSLog(@"Filename: %@", filename);
        // Get the path to the App's Documents directory
        NSString *docPath = [self documentsDirectoryPath];
        // Combine the filename and the path to the documents dir into the full path
        NSString *pathToDownloadTo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, filename];


        // Load the file from the remote server
        NSData *tmp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theResourcesURL];
        // Save the loaded data if loaded successfully
        if (tmp != nil) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            // Write the contents of our tmp object into a file
            [tmp writeToFile:pathToDownloadTo options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
            if (error != nil) {
                UIAlertView *filenameErrorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Saving" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The file %@ could not be saved. Please try again.", filename] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [filenameErrorAlert show];
                [filenameErrorAlert release];

                NSLog(@"Failed to save the file: %@", [error description]);
            } else {
                // Display an UIAlertView that shows the users we saved the file :)
                UIAlertView *filenameAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"File saved" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The file %@ has been saved.", filename] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [filenameAlert show];
                [filenameAlert release];
            }
        } else {

            NSLog(@"Error, file could not be saved");

        }
}

else 

{

    NSLog(@"Error, could not find button index!");

}
}
```

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the `UIActionSheet` delegate to `nil`. In this context, you want to set it to `self`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the delegate to self

```
UIActionSheet *saveFileSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:@"iDHSB Download Centre" 
                       delegate:self 
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"  
                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                       otherButtonTitles:@"Download File", @"Show My Files", nil] 
                      autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re creating the action sheet with a `nil` delegate, so the delegate methods you implemented will never get called. Pass `self` as the delegate in the action sheet’s initializer and it should work.